# Решение геометрической задачи

Tags: python, геометрия

У меня имеется задача:
Имеются 2 прямых дороги, заданные точками начала и конца AB и CD соответвтенно. Точка представляет собой географическую координату (широта и долгота). Нужно попасть из точки A в точку D. Перемещаться можно только по дорогам. Необходимо реализовать функцию route_exist, которая возвращает истину в случае существования такого маршрута.

Эту задачу необходимо реализовать на python

Я очень не силен в геометрии и даже не могу понять как просто устно реализовать данную задачу
Может кто помочь?

Смог задать только классы

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    latitude: float # Широта
    longitude: float # Долгота


@dataclass
class Road:
    start_point: Point
    end_point: Point


def route_exist(road_1: Road, road_2: Road) -> bool:
     pass
```

Comment: Ну, если я верно понял, то весь вопрос в том, пересекаются ли отрезки AB и CD... А дальше вопрос в том, сильно ли большие эти отрезки — ну, там, в пределах 100 км, чтоб считать координаты просто координатами на плоскости, или надо уже использовать сферическую геометрию...

Comment: А как здесь использовать сферическую геометрию? Просто я помню какие-то самые основы геометрии из школы, и эта задачка не поддаётся моему понимаю)

Comment: Ну поищите что-то типа https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5

Comment: Сферическая геометрия не нужна. Конкретно в этой задаче можно обойтись трёхмерными векторами, векторным и скалярным произведениями.

Comment: Минусующие, выскажитесь, пожалуйста. Я понимаю что нет попыток решения, но и задача не сказать чтобы тривиальная и учебная. Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Я если честно и сам уже отчаялся, публика на стаке довольно специфичная и тебя могут заминусовать за что угодно

Comment: Да за лишённый всякой полезной информации заголовок минусы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любая пара точек, если они различные и не диаметрально противоположные, задаёт на сфере [большой круг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3), который определяется плоскостью, построенной на центре сферы и этих двух точках. Плоскость задаётся нормальным вектором *n*: *n = c×d*, где *c* и *d* - точки задающие плоскость (трехмерные вектора единичной длины), *×* - [векторное произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Дуга между точками *a* и *b* пересечёт большой круг, если [скалярные произведения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) *a<sub>n</sub> = n **·** a* и *b<sub>n</sub> = n **·** b* имеют разные знаки.

Пусть оказалось что *a<sub>n</sub> < 0 < b<sub>n</sub>* (если это не так, поменяем их местами чтобы стало так). Тогда можно вычислить точку на плоскости большого круга между *a* и *b*. Эта точка равна *b<sub>n</sub>a - a<sub>n</sub>b*. Если эту точку (вектор) нормализовать, получим точку пересечения дуги от *a* до *b* с большим кругом заданным *с* и *d*.

Вычислим *i<sub>ab</sub>* - пересечение дуги *ab* с большим кругом *cd*.

Вычислим *i<sub>cd</sub>* - пересечение дуги *cd* с большим кругом *ab*.

Возможны следующие ситуации:

1. *i<sub>ab</sub>* не существует, так как дуга *ab* не пересекает большой круг *cd*. Тогда дуги *ab* и *cd* не пересекаются.

   Пример: *a = 10°, 10°*, *b = 20°, 10°* - кусок меридиана в северном полушарии. *с = 0°, 0°*, *d = 0°, 20°* - кусок экватора.
2. *i<sub>cd</sub>* не существует, так как дуга *cd* не пересекает большой круг *ab*. Тогда дуги *ab* и *cd* не пересекаются.

   Пример: *a = 10°, 10°*, *b = -10°, 10°* - кусок меридиана в районе экватора. *с = 0°, 20°*, *d = 0°, 30°* - кусок экватора.
3. *i<sub>ab</sub>* и *i<sub>cd</sub>* существуют обе и диаметрально противоположны. Дуги *ab* и *cd* не пересекаются, хотя каждая из них пересекает большой круг другой дуги. Бывает.

   Пример: *a = 10°, 0°*, *b = -10°, 0°* - кусок нулевого меридиана в районе экватора. *с = 0°, 170°*, *d = 0°, -170°* - кусок экватора с противоположной стороны.
4. *i<sub>ab</sub>* и *i<sub>cd</sub>* существуют и совпадают. Пересечение найдено. Ура!

   Пример: *a = 10°, 10°*, *b = -10°, 10°* - кусок меридиана. *с = 0°, 0°*, *d = 0°, 20°* - кусок экватора.

Код реализует описанный алгоритм. Все случаи где решение может выродится (совпадающие точки, противолежащие точки) нормально обрабатываются. Единственная ситуация, которая не обработана - когда обе дуги лежат на одном большом круге. Программа в этом случае возвращает что пересечения нет, даже если дуги перекрываются.

```
import math


# скалярное произведение
def dot(a, b):
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2]


# векторное произведение
def cross(a, b):
    return                         \
        a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], \
        a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], \
        a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]


# (широта, долгота) -> (x, y, z)
def to_3d(lat_long_deg):
    lat, long = map(math.radians, lat_long_deg)
    lat_c = math.cos(lat)
    return lat_c * math.cos(long), lat_c * math.sin(long), math.sin(lat)


def are_intersected(arc1, arc2):

    # это не настоящее пересечение круга и дуги
    # вектор, который возвращается:
    #   сонаправлен с точкой пересечения, если пересечение есть
    #   равен нулю, если пересечения нет
    # этого достаточно для финального теста
    def intersection(circle, arc):
        n = cross(*circle)
        a, b = arc
        a_n = dot(n, a)
        b_n = dot(n, b)
        if a_n > b_n:
            a, b = b, a
            a_n, b_n = b_n, a_n
        if a_n <= 0 <= b_n:
            return                       \
                b_n * a[0] - a_n * b[0], \
                b_n * a[1] - a_n * b[1], \
                b_n * a[2] - a_n * b[2]
        # fake intersection
        return 0, 0, 0

    arc1_3d = tuple(map(to_3d, arc1))
    arc2_3d = tuple(map(to_3d, arc2))

    # если оба вектора не нули
    # и если они сонаправлены,
    # то их скалярное произведение будет больше нуля.
    # в этом случае дуги пересекаются
    return dot(
        intersection(arc1_3d, arc2_3d),
        intersection(arc2_3d, arc1_3d)
    ) > 0


print(are_intersected(
    ((10, 10), (20, 20)),
    ((20, 10), (10, 20))
))
```